# How to make a function affect everything with a class but also take into account a data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a comments system for my site and want to have the time since posted update at a set interval. Currently my javascript only takes into account one data-time attribute for every class but I want it to use each classes data-time attribute.

My html looks something a little like this

```
<div class="commentTime noSelect" data-time="1424867042">0 days and 0 hours and 5 minutes and 40 seconds</div>

<div class="commentTime noSelect" data-time="1424863061">0 days and 0 hours and 5 minutes and 40 seconds</div>

<div class="commentTime noSelect" data-time="1424861992">0 days and 0 hours and 5 minutes and 40 seconds</div>

etc...
```

data-time is the time in seconds since 1970. Now here's my javascript.

```
    //Time Update Function

    function time_elapsed() {

            time = $(".commentTime").attr("data-time");
            currentTime = new Date().getTime() / 1000;

            time = currentTime - time;

            var days = Math.floor(time / 86400);
            var hours = Math.floor((time - (days * 86400 ))/3600);
            var minutes = Math.floor((time - (days * 86400 ) - (hours *3600 ))/60);
            var seconds = Math.floor((time - (days * 86400 ) - (hours *3600 ) - (minutes*60)));

            if ( seconds > 1 ){ updatedTime = seconds + " seconds"; }else{ updatedTime = seconds + " second"; }
            if ( minutes > 1 ){ updatedTime = minutes + " minutes and " + updatedTime; }else{ updatedTime = minutes + " minute and " + updatedTime;  }
            if ( minutes > 1 ){ updatedTime = hours + " hours and " + updatedTime; }else{ updatedTime = hours + " hour and " + updatedTime;  }
            if ( minutes > 1 ){ updatedTime = days + " days and " + updatedTime; }else{ updatedTime = days + " day and " + updatedTime;  }

            $(".commentTime").html(updatedTime);

        }

    setInterval(time_elapsed(),1000);
```

I'm pretty new to javascript and I just can't seem to make it treat each div uniquely.

Comment: You realize that you should be passing the function `time_elepsed` to `setInterval` not the result of the function? Both answers have corrected this for you but its quite subtle, so thought you might miss it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like that, see also Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ApfJz/37/:

```
function time_elapsed() {
    $(".commentTime").each(function(){

        var time = $(this).attr("data-time");
        var currentTime = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
        var updatedTime;

        time = currentTime - time;

        var days = Math.floor(time / 86400);
        var hours = Math.floor((time - (days * 86400 ))/3600);
        var minutes = Math.floor((time - (days * 86400 ) - (hours *3600 ))/60);
        var seconds = Math.floor((time - (days * 86400 ) - (hours *3600 ) - (minutes*60)));

        if ( seconds > 1 ){ updatedTime = seconds + " seconds"; }else{ updatedTime = seconds + " second"; }
        if ( minutes > 1 ){ updatedTime = minutes + " minutes and " + updatedTime; }else{ updatedTime = minutes + " minute and " + updatedTime;  }
        if ( minutes > 1 ){ updatedTime = hours + " hours and " + updatedTime; }else{ updatedTime = hours + " hour and " + updatedTime;  }
        if ( minutes > 1 ){ updatedTime = days + " days and " + updatedTime; }else{ updatedTime = days + " day and " + updatedTime;  }

        $(this).html(updatedTime);
    });
    }

setInterval(time_elapsed,1000);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, same to dhunt. This is EXACTLY what I was looking for. I didn't know about each() but it's perfect and works perfectly. You guys are brilliant!

Comment: No problem, do not hesitate to approve answer if it is what satisfy you ;-)

Comment: Done, sorry bit late, I completely forgot about that part!

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is when you select the time it takes it from $(".commentTime"); which select more than one element. You have to select them all and loop through - treating each one individually. This could be tidied up further but I think this should work:

```
function time_elapsed() {
    $(".commentTime").each(function(){
        time = $(this).attr("data-time");
        currentTime = new Date().getTime() / 1000;

        time = currentTime - time;

        var days = Math.floor(time / 86400);
        var hours = Math.floor((time - (days * 86400 ))/3600);
        var minutes = Math.floor((time - (days * 86400 ) - (hours *3600     ))/60);
        var seconds = Math.floor((time - (days * 86400 ) - (hours *3600 ) - (minutes*60)));

        updatedTime = seconds + " second" + (seconds == 1 ? "" : "s");
        updatedTime = minutes + " minute" + (minutes == 1 ? "" : "s")  + " and " + updatedTime;
        updatedTime = hours + " hour" + (hours == 1 ? "" : "s") + " and " + updatedTime;
        updatedTime = days + " day" + (days == 1 ? "" : "s") + " and " + updatedTime;

        $(this).html(updatedTime);
    });
}

setInterval(time_elapsed,1000);
```

Comment: do you need `i` and `element`? You never use `i` and `element` is just `this` inside the loop.

Comment: You could use 'this' and not have them - its just an explicit parameter to the same object. I have also included a shorter way of doing pluralisation